EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes when iOS app resigned/deployed to Enterprise MDM account
We are seeing many EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes while trying to read from the local sqlite db on our app. We ONLY see these crashes when we push the app to one of our vendors who will resign the app with their bundle ID and then distribute via their MDM using their Enterprise cert.
These crashes never show up when we run the exact same app with our Enterprise certificate and download directly to our devices.
The entitlements look correct for the clients Certs/Profiles.
The resign tool they use is: https://www.iosappsigner.com/
The MDM they use is InTune
Any ideas why this would happen? Could it be a failure on the resign tool (we recently saw issues with that resign tool for another client and found success using iResign) or could it be a restriction on the MDM InTune security policies or?
Thanks,
J
